# How to define PopUp style errors in netLogo

Tags: netlogo

Is there any way to throw errors as pop uos in netlogo . Say, i have two buttons, if i am pressing the second one without clicking one the first one to setup the system then I should get an error in the pop up saying you cant run without pressing the first button.

Answer (score 1):

There sure is! Check out [error](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#error). You use it like so:

`error "Something went terribly wrong!"`

Comment: You might also consider [`user-message`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/5.0/docs/dictionary.html#user-message).

Comment: Can you tell me how to code the situation to throw an error if a button is pressed before the other.?

Comment: Would you mind opening up a new question ask that? Also, please describe what you're trying to do in a little detail and describe what you've tried.